# Issue with jbake-maven-plugin

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, netbeans, jbake

I'm following the dukes-age example application from https://javaee.github.io/firstcup/creating-example002.html, and I'm facing an issue when trying to build the dukes-age.war.

The error received on building is:

```
Failed to execute goal from com.blazebit:jbake-maven-plugin:1.0.0:build (build-site) on project dukes-age: Failure when running: Error: Source folder must exist: ... -> [Help 1]
```

I've changed the pom.xml file as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <artifactId>firstcup</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.docs</groupId>
    <version>8.0</version>
</parent>

<groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
<artifactId>dukes-age</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>dukes-age</name>

<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.blazebit</groupId>
        <artifactId>jbake-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.blazebit</groupId>
            <artifactId>jbake-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>build</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <properties>
                            <site.url>http://localhost:8820/</site.url>
                        </properties>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the BlazeBit version of the JBake Maven Plugin to build the duke-ages.war I'd suggest you comment out the dependency and the plugin section for this and try again.